# DolphinDB: Issues with filling NULL values in DolphinDB

Tags: interpolation, dolphindb

I now have a table where the data of the 21st, 24th, 25th, and 28th seconds are stored but the data of the 22nd, 23rd and 26th seconds are missing. What can I use to replace the NULL values? I’d like to fill in the vacancy with the value of the previous non null data and to fill that of the 22nd and 23rd seconds with the 21st-second value.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using function `interval`.

First create a table based on existing data:

```py
time = [15:20:21,15:20:24,15:20:25,15:20:28]
values = [1,2,5,3]
t = table(time as time,values as values1)
```

The table is:

[image]

Then, fill in the empty values:

```py
t1= select last(values1) from t group by interval(time,1s,'prev') as time
```

The updated table is:

[image]